# Removing part of img src

Tags: jquery, image, src

I have 20 images and the same 20 images with a different color called in the same name but the second with a suffix "_blu" -> "google.jpg" and the other one "google_blu.jpg"
I would make a Mouseover to change that from one to the other.

I tried like this but i've no idea how to target the image (i can say "every image inside the class .hovertondo)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".hovertondo").css("opacity","1");

    $(".hovertondo").hover(function () {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).attr('src', src.replace('_blu', ''));
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0}, "slow");

        },function () {$(this).stop().animate({opacity: 1}, "slow");
                       $(this).attr('src', src.replace('_blu', ''));

        });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="conttondodentosofia">
<img src="http://studiodentisticocova.com/img/trattamenti/carie_blu.jpg" />
<div class="hovertondo">Carie</div>
</div>
```

I opened it with firebug and the error is

> "TypeError: $(...).attr(...) is undefined" (talking about this line $(this).attr('src', src.replace('_blu', ''));)

Does anyone hep me? :)
thanks!

Comment: You can simplify this by getting and setting `this.src` instead of using `$(this).attr(src)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src` is not defined in your mouseleave handler (second parameter of `hover` method) :

Change this

```
$(".hovertondo").hover(function () {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).attr('src', src.replace('_blu', ''));
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0}, "slow");

        },function () {$(this).stop().animate({opacity: 1}, "slow");
                       $(this).attr('src', src.replace('_blu', ''));

        });
```

To

```
$(".hovertondo").hover(function () {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).attr('src', src.replace('_blu', ''));
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0}, "slow");

        },function () {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 1}, "slow");
        $(this).attr('src', src.replace('_blu', ''));

        });
```

BTW, you are making `$(this).attr('src', src.replace('_blu', ''));` in both cases. There is a case when you have to add '_blu' to your src. It would give something like that : `$(this).attr('src', src.replace('.jpg', '_blu.jpg'));`

**EDIT**

You can have a smooth image modification by using `fadeOut` method :

```
$('this').fadeOut(300, function(){
      $(this).attr('src', src.replace('_blu', '')).bind('onreadystatechange load', function(){
         if (this.complete) $(this).fadeIn(300);
      });
   });
```

Comment: Oops, I have to retract my previous comment because I forgot about needing the `.jpg` on the end. Still, `this.src=this.src.replace(...`

Comment: i'll try but if you read the question I have a problem too to point the image. As you can see in the part of html I'm working on a class and the image it's not cointained in that class ;)

Comment: Just change selector to `$("div.conttondodentosofia img")`

Comment: `$(this).closest("div.conttondodentosofia").find("img")`

Comment: I can't! 
what i want to do is this:
- modify the objects with .hovertondo class 
AND
- change the src of some images

See example here: http://studiodentisticocova.com/img/perstack.jpg

Comment: UP: i solved it :)
is there a way to smooth the change of that? the transition between the images

Comment: Yes, you can use `fadeOut` method : `$('this').fadeOut(300, function(){
      $(this).attr('src', src.replace('_blu', '')).bind('onreadystatechange load', function(){
         if (this.complete) $(this).fadeIn(300);
      });
   });`. I add it in my answer.

Comment: it works but I would do it together. Like you wrote it does before a fadeOut and when it finished it starts the fadeIn. How can I do it at the same time?
btw: really thanks for your help and sorry for my questions but I'm still a noob :)

Comment: You can't, since you have to wait for the image to be loaded to display it. Maybe you can try something like this : `$('this').attr('src', src.replace('_blu', '')).fadeIn('slow').delay(200).fadeOut('slow');`